# Apache Wildcard Rewriting Subdomain to a Sub Directory

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Been trying to Rewrite wildcard subdomain to a subdirectory and not having allot of luck.

ie

abc.domain.com > www.domain.com/sub/abc

I have tried the folowing

```
// example 1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./sub/$1 [L]

// example 2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./sub/$1 [L]
```

Hope someone can advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use backreference from `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!(?:sub|index\.php)/).*)$ ./sub/%1/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks.  Im getting Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects. ie,
[Tue Feb 24 16:43:44 2015] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 192.168.1.108] redirected from r->uri = /index.php/sub/abc/
[Tue Feb 24 16:43:44 2015] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 192.168.1.108] redirected from r->uri = /sub/abc/

Comment: Are you sure you have rule as: `RewriteRule ^((?!sub/).*)$ ./sub/%1/$1 [L,NC]` That will not rewrite if request uri already has `/sub/`

Comment: Yea 100%. I clear apache log and its displaying:  http://kopy.io/uufCc#qydtYtC6aJ3VAL

Comment: ok can you place your complete and latest .htaccess in question

Comment: From your logs it looks like there is some rule writing it to `/index.php/...`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71605/discussion-between-lee-and-anubhava).